# How to get the innerHTML through val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td class="value" style="width:40%;">
    <select>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="1">two</option>
        <option value="1">three</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

I am finding the val() by using below code:

```
  $(this).closest("td").next().find("select").each(function(){
                selectValues.push($(this).val());
            });
```

Please refer this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/WCf8P/2/). I want to get the innerHTML of the Option using val().

*Like:* **$(this).val().innerHTML**

Please suggest any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the text of the selected option so

```
selectValues.push($(this).find('option:selected').text());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5f68h/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$('td select option [value=1]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get it with `.text()`

```
selectValues.push($(':selected',this).text());
```

#### [Check your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCf8P/5/)

---

Even you can use `.map()` method to create arrays:

```
var selectValues = $(this).closest("td").next().find("select").map(function(){
      return $(':selected',this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `text()`

```
$(this).closest("td").next().find("select").each(function(){
    selectValues.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting selected option inner text use this

```
selectValues.push($(this).find('option:selected').html());
```

or

```
selectValues.push($(this).find('option:selected').text());
```

For getting selected option value

```
selectValues.push($(this).val()); // It return value of the option
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work perfect only problem is HTML Code you are set all `<option>` element `value="1"` that's why this problem occur now you can check following jsFiddle

#### Check <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCf8P/4/)**</kbd>

#### Update HTML

```
<select>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: While it is not fully clear from the question, is more likely that the OP wants to have the `innerHtml` of the currently selected option. But this is something the OP must decide.